# MIPS - Revision convert java fragment into MIPS. Made program but prints wrong number?

Tags: assembly, mips

Question. Write MIPS assembley code which is equivalent to the following Java code fragment.

```
    int x = 1 ;
    int y = 3 ;
    int c = 2 ;
    x = y - c ;
    if (x != y) { x = y + 5 ; }
    else { x = c ; } ;
```

This is what I have at the moment.

```
.data 
X: .word 1
Y: .word 3
C: .word 2
.text
main:
la $t1, X 
la $t2, Y
la $t3, C
lw $t1, ($t1)
lw $t2, ($t2)
lw $t3, ($t3)
sub $t1, $t2, $t3
li $v0, 1
beq $t1, $t2, iflabel
add $t1,$t3, 0 # sets x = c by adding zero to c and putting result in $t1 (register for x) used.
iflabel: add $t1,$t2,5
syscall
li $v0, 10
```

As Far as I can tell '8' should be printed, but instead 0 is ?!?, not a homework question, just some revision question on MIPS. I can guess that my syscall 's are probably in the wrong places and possibly causing the error maybe?, I'm using MARS to program in, as I can see the contents of the register and run each line one by one, but still doesn't help my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are backwards: right now you have it so that is X *is equal to* Y it'll add 5, but from the Java code it looks like you want it the other way around:

```
bne $t1, $t2, iflabel
```

Secondly, your +5 code flows into the other condition. You need a label after the if/else block, and you need to branch to it after handling the if-true code.

Thirdly, you should be loading the `$v0` vector immediately before doing syscall, and there's no reason to be doing it afterward.

Fourthly, [syscall 1](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) needs the integer to be in `$a0.` You can directly add Y+5 or C+0 into `$a0`.

Final code should be:

```
.data 
X: .word 1
Y: .word 3
C: .word 2

.text
main:
la $t1, X 
la $t2, Y
la $t3, C
lw $t1, ($t1)
lw $t2, ($t2)
lw $t3, ($t3)
sub $t1, $t2, $t3
bne $t1, $t2, iflabel
add $a0,$t3, 0
b endif
iflabel: add $a0,$t2,5
endif:
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Comment: There should really be .align 2 for X (the rest will follow since they are words anyway). That is an alignment restriction. Simulators might be forgiving; the real world does not. Secondly, Java silently ignores overflows, therefore sub and add should be subu and addu since they don't trap.

Comment: Alright It's working now thank you, $a0 is the argument register, and that is where things are from that get printed on screen, Abit rusty with MIPS, seems I got the bne/beq mixed up and not jumping past the else statement, I was taught to test on failure, but still seems as if I made mistake either way. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Is your integer in the right register? Seems from [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) that it should be in `$a0`